# Placing value from script to the DOM

Tags: javascript, html

I have to create a droplist, and `onchange` the value must be written in some `<div>` or `<p>`.

This is my code. I am tottaly stuck; maybe just a few hints would do the job.

```js
function beerFunction(beer) {
  var y = beer.value;
  
  return y;
}

function beerChoice() {
  var x = getElementById("paragraf");
  
  x.innerHTML = "So" + y + "is your beer of choice? Interesting facts about " + y + ": ";
}
```

```html
<h1>Your Fav Beer:</h1>
<select onchange="beerFunction(this)">
  <option>Jelen</option>
  <option>Lav</option>
  <option>Jagodinsko</option>
  <option>Nikšićko</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<h2>Answer:</h2>
<p id="paragraf">
  <script>
  </script>
</p>
```

Comment: Please see the [examples on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/change). `return y;` is meaningless — where do you return to? You should _call_ `beerChoice` with the _parameter_ `y` somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

A few things here:

**(1):** The function that is changing the element on the page is `beerChoice()`, right? You've written a definition for that function, but you never actually execute the function, so none of that ever happens.

**(2):** You're returning `y` in your `beerFunction()`, but this would be the perfect time to, instead, call your `beerChoice()` function. You've got the beer the user has selected, you now need to let the page know to change the text.

**(3):** Because you've declared `y` *inside of `beerFunction()`*, it will *only be available within `beerFunction()`* - your `beerChoice()` function will not be able to access it. The proper way to do this would be to instead *pass it as an argument*, like `beerChoice(y)`.

**(4):** `getElementById` must be prefixed with `document`. You'll want to change that line to `document.getElementById("paragraf")`.

**(5):** What helps me personally when I'm writing code, is to name the functions very clearly as to *what they do*. That way, when you're thinking in your head about what needs to happen next, you don't need to spend as much time trying to translate it into code, or figure out *"Which function was changing the text again?"*. If your next step is "Change the Beer Text", then perhaps name your function `changeBeerText()`. Similarly, you'll find coding much easier if you name all your variables clearly too.

```js
function onBeerSelectionChange(beer) {
  var beerName = beer.value;
  changeBeerText(beerName);
}

function changeBeerText(beerName) {
  var paragraph = document.getElementById("paragraf");
  paragraph.innerHTML = "So" + beerName+ "is your beer of choice? Interesting facts about " + beerName + ": ";
}
```

```html
<select onchange="onBeerSelectionChange(this)">
  <option>Jelen</option>
  <option>Lav</option>
  <option>Jagodinsko</option>
  <option>Nikšićko</option>
</select><br><br>

<h2>Answer:</h2>
<p id="paragraf">
  <script>
  </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Add `document.` before getElementById
2. Add beerChoice() around the return value in your `beerFunction`

```js
function beerFunction(beer) {
  var y = beer.value;
  return beerChoice(y);
}

function beerChoice(y) {
  var x = document.getElementById("paragraf");
  x.innerHTML = "So" + y + "is your beer of choice? Interesting facts about " + y + ": ";
}
```

```html
<select onchange="beerFunction(this)">
  <option>Jelen</option>
  <option>Lav</option>
  <option>Jagodinsko</option>
  <option>Nikšićko</option>
</select><br><br>

<h2>Answer:</h2>
<p id="paragraf">
  <script>
  </script>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're close. In your code `beerFunction` is the event handler, but you aren't doing anything with it. Since the change event will be invoked *asynchronously* you need to make sure that everything you need to do with that event is done either by that handler, or by a function called in that handler.

```js
function beerFunction(beer) {
  var y = beer.value;
  beerChoice(y);//we need to pass the value to the function that will update the dom
}

function beerChoice(y) {
  //getElementById is a method of the document object
  var x = document.getElementById("paragraf");
  x.innerHTML = "So " + y + " is your beer of choice? Interesting facts about " + y + ": ";
}
```

```html
<select onchange="beerFunction(this)">
  <option>Jelen</option>
  <option>Lav</option>
  <option>Jagodinsko</option>
  <option>Nikšićko</option>
</select><br><br>

<h2>Answer:</h2>
<p id="paragraf">
  <script>
  </script>
</p>
```